# cant run Google cloud "ValueError: Authorized user info was not..."

Tags: python, google-api

I'm trying to run `quickstart.py` for the Google Drive Python API and I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Authorized user info was not in the expected format, missing fields client_id, client_secret, refresh_token.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Whats the format of your credentials.json file? (redact all the sensitive data)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google API Python | ValueError: Authorized user info was not in the expected format, missing fields client\_secret, client\_id, refresh\_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75607363/google-api-python-valueerror-authorized-user-info-was-not-in-the-expected-for)

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `xx.json` file to the format below:

```json
{
    "project_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", 
    "client_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "client_secret":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "redirect_uris":["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxx"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. What I did was to make use of service account so that my script can have access to the drive.

```
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            filename=service_account_file_path,
            scopes=SCOPES
        )
drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
results = drive.files().list().execute()
files = results.get('files', [])
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes looking for an answer here, please note that a valid answer was posted at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75607363/google-api-python-valueerror-authorized-user-info-was-not-in-the-expected-for).

In short, do not download and rename the credentials file to `token.json`. Just run the script without any token file in the directory. On the first run, when the code finds no valid token file, it fires up the browser and takes you to the authorization page. On giving access, the token file is created for you.